# Creating a file server in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-files

Our company has an on-prem file server that I'd like to move to the cloud. I followed [these directions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/09/22/step-by-step-creating-a-file-share-in-azure/) and was successfully able to map a drive on my local work computer to connect to an Azure File Share. Our company has about 20 locations, ~5 TB of data (mostly "office" type of files) in total, and about 500 users accessing them.

There are two issues I would like to improve but I'm not sure how:

1. There's somewhat of a lag when opening files. Other than increasing our office's internet speed, is there anything to be done to make it faster? Would some kind of site-to-site VPN help? Would adding some type of server or VM in the "middle" (maybe one per location?) that would perhaps somehow cache the files reduce the lag?
2. Also, we have and use an Office 365 subscription. What's the easiest way to use our existing AD structure to transfer over the NTFS permissions that are currently in place?

I Googled around and found a bunch of companies advertising their services, notable among them was [Talon Storage](https://www.talonstorage.com/). But it seems like something that could be done without hiring a company. What I'm hoping for is a DIY direction to optimally solve these issues. Perhaps there's a standard or commonly recommended solution for such issues. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

L-A-T-E-N-C-Y. The number one enemy for any cloud-based file server attempt. It ranges from annoying to down right unusable, depending on how far you are from the Azure datacenter of choice.

Imagine a poor soul trying to "stream" a large 20-meg Excel file with 20 references to external files. What used to take maybe 8 seconds on-prem will now take 40 in the cloud (on a good day). It's game over for productivity. Your marketing department that sometimes used to cut video in iMovie over the network? Those days are over.

I understand this is not the answer you were after, but it's the crude reality.
Do not panic, there are solutions, here's a good one - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storsimple/

I'm sure you wanted to get rid of boxes not buy more, but it is what it is.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: in such a scenario, would MPLS eliminate most of the latency?

Comment: It's just the economics of light speed. MPLS is encapsulation, they're going to use the same physical wires between exchanges while offering an SLA figure on top. Not gonna help with latency. Check this out if you don't know about it already - http://www.azurespeed.com/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for the link! Didn't have that one in my favs